# How to calculate $ e^{0.1} $ using taylor inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

How can I calculate $ e^{0.1} $ using Taylor series and Inequality.
I know that the formula is $ | R_n (x) | \leq \dfrac {M | x- a|^{n+1}} {(n+1)!} $

But I dont know how to apply it

Comment: $ M=1$. But your question is utterly incomplete

Comment: Your $a$ is probably $0$ and so your $M$ is $e^{0.1}$ (since all of the derivatives are $e^x$ and your Lagrange remainder "$\xi$" is between $0$ and $0.1$). Thus you are left to choose $n$ large enough that $e^{0.1} \frac{0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ is less than whatever your absolute error tolerance is. This can be more conveniently stated as making $\frac{0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ be less than your *relative* error tolerance, if you have a relative error tolerance in mind. If you don't...well, $e^{0.1}$ is certainly less than $2$...

Comment: From where did you get $ e^{0.1} \frac{0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $ ?
My a is in fact 0, and my error tolerance is 0.00005
But I dont recognize the formula you applied

Comment: The Lagrange error is exactly $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi) (x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, where $\xi$ is an unknown number between $x$ and $a$. In your case this becomes $\frac{e^\xi 0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $0.1$. But $e^\xi$ on $[0,0.1]$ is maximized at $0.1$, so you get a bound of $\frac{e^{0.1} 0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$. To use an absolute error estimate rather than a relative error estimate, you will then need an upper bound on $e^{0.1}$.

Comment: By using Lagrange I get that the error is less than $ 5*10^5 $ when $ n > 4 $ , does that mean that If I sum the taylor series up to order 5, $ e^{0.1} - T_5^{f,0} < 0.00005 $ ?
If it is so, on the taylor series, when I sum the terms, what should I use instead of $ e^{0.1} $
And what's the value of x in each term of $ \dfrac {f^(n)(0)} {n!} (x)^n $

Comment: To replace $e^{0.1}$ you're going to need to know something about the exponential function. I'll give a hint that $e^{0.1} \leq 2$ and leave it to you to prove that. So now you need to find $n$ such that $\frac{e^{0.1} 0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<5 \cdot 10^{-5}$. Then the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial evaluated at $0.1$ will be within $5 \cdot 10^{-5}$ of $e^{0.1}$.